# Value setting to default value after coming back in page

Tags: angularjs

I have selected the second values in drop down, the value is should remain same ,when i got to next page and come back the value gets changed to the first one.
so someone could help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Your current controller gets destroyed when you navigate to another state/view. If you want to retain your value then store that value in service using `setDropdownValue(value)` while navigating to another state and get that value from service using `getDropdownValue()` when your controller is getting loaded. You can check below example:

```
  app.service('dataService', function() {
    var dropdownvalue = null;

      this.setDropdownValue= function (value) {
        dropdownvalue = value;
      };

    this.getDropdownValue= function () {
        return dropdownvalue;
      }
    });

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.dropdownVariable= dataService.getDropdownValue();

// While changing view call dataService.setDropdownValue($scope.dropdownVariable);
});
```